# How do I stop a for loop from looping over subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell

If in a #!/bin/bash script I have:

`FILES="/path/to/files/"` and that path contains files, and I insert this:

```
for f in $FILES
  do
    thing
  done
```

I get no result.

If I change `FILES="/path/to/files/*` then the loop runs and I get results.  However, if part of the loop involves building a file folder structure beneath `/path/to/files/`, i.e. `/path/to/files/folder1` `folder2` etc., then on a subsequent run, those folders become part of the iteration.

So, is there a way to set the depth on the `$FILES` path so the for loop will only ever look at just that folder?

Comment: Can you use zsh instead?

Comment: Know nothing about it and I'm very new to bash scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shawn said in his comment, this would be easier in zsh, but in bash, you would do a

```
for f in /path/to/files/*
do
  if [[ ! -d $f ]]
  then
    thing
  fi
done
```

Note that this would skip files where the name starts with a period; but this was also present in your own attempt, and I assume that this is what you want.

Comment: The zsh way being `/path/to/files/*(.)`, which limits the filename expansion to just regular files.

Comment: Isn't it what the OP wants here? BTW, you can also do `/path/to/files/{*(.),*(@N)}` if you want to include symlinks.

Comment: @Shawn : Or, in case the OP really wants to catch **everything except** directories, the zsh pattern would be `/path/to/files/*(^/)`. This would actually be semantically closest to my bash-solution.

Comment: Just everything in that single folder that is *.mp4, nothing else.  Fortunately none of the files created have any spaces in them and they're all named similarly, so there's no risk of spaces etc.

Comment: @JonGriffith: Actually, my proposal would also work with filenames containing spaces or newlines. Just make sure that inside _thing_, you quote `$f` where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will only loop through files of the **present** folder,
but will exclude subdirectories.

```
export selectedFiles=`ls -p | grep -v /`
for f in $selectedFiles
  do
    echo $f
  done
```

For **any other folder**, please store directory path in "theFolder", like shown below.

```
export theFolder="/home/user/thedirectory"
export selectedFiles=`ls $theFolder -p | grep -v /`
for f in $selectedFiles
  do
    echo $f
  done
```